# Where is ResultSetTableModel class located?

Tags: java

In which package is the `ResultSetTableModel` class written?
I've faced an error that cannot find symbol, and I can't seem to find it anywhere in the whole JDK library.

Comment: It is a third party class. You will need to add external jars.

Comment: "In which package is the ResultSetTableModel class written" ... you tell us. Your error message should say.

Comment: There are multiple implementation of `ResultSetTableModel`. Search the web and download a version that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are talking about `com.ibm.as400.vaccess.SQLResultSetTableModel` class. You will need to add the `jt400-full-5.2.jar` in your build path.

Answer (score 0):

public class ResultSetTableModel
extends java.lang.Object
implements javax.swing.table.TableModel 
at this locationa you can find ResultSetTableModel you should have to implement javax.swing.table.TableModel